# Retrieve multiple form field parameters in a multipart enctype form

Tags: jsp, tomcat, file-upload

I have 2 normal text fields and 1 upload field to be parsed. The `getFieldName();` as suggested in the [Apache Tomcat FileUpload page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html#Processing_the_uploaded_items)  seems to only get the name attribute of the `input` html tag and not the parameter entered.

`getRelDate = fi.getFieldName();` has the result of 'date'.

Also, if I use `getFieldName()` for both of the normal text fields, they are of the same result.

How do I get the parameters of multiple normal text fields ?

**The Html code:**

```
<!-- normal text fields -->
<td>Release Date</td>
<td><input type='text' size=30 name='date'></td>

<td>Apple</td>
<td><input type='text' size=30 name='apple'></td>

<!-- upload field -->
<td>Image Upload</td>
<td><input type='file' size=30 name='imagefile'></td>
```

**The JSP code:**

```
String getRelDate   = "";
String getApple     = "";

  try{ 
     // Parse the request to get file items.
     List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

     // Process the uploaded file items
     Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

     while ( i.hasNext () ) 
     {
        FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();

    if ( fi.isFormField () ){
     getRelDate = fi.getFieldName();
     getApple   = fi.getFieldName();
    }

    // Get the uploaded file parameters

    File file2 = new File(filePath,fi.getName());

    fi.write(file2);

    out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + fi.getName() + "<br>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're iterating over the form fields, and for each one, setting *both* `getRelDate` *and* `getApple` to the name of the field.

Second, you're setting field *names*, instead of field *values*.

Consider [reading over the documentation for the libraries you try to use](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html#Processing_the_uploaded_items).

Nutshell is that if it's a simple form field, use `getString()` to return field content.

If it's a file, there are a few options detailed in the link provided above.

Comment: Hi, after some tinkering with the code, a `fi.getString("date")` may work. But I can't figure out how to get a set of array values. Previously, it is `getParameterValues()`, but this method doesn't work anymore too. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: @iridescent IIRC you'd just keep calling `getFieldName()` and add items with the same name to a collection.